# removeClass( ) from a span within a <td>

Tags: javascript, html, removeclass

> I want to remove class .highlights from span which is inside a td
>   having class .remove_highlight.

```
<tr id="row1" class="remove table_row highlight">
  <td class="remove_highlight">7499</td>
  <td><span class="highlights">AL</span>LEN</td>
  **<td class="remove_highlight">S<span class="highlights">AL</span>ESMAN</td>**
  <td class="remove_highlight">7698</td>
  <td class="remove_highlight">1981-02-20</td>
  <td class="remove_highlight">1600.00</td>
  <td class="remove_highlight">300.00</td>
  <td class="remove_highlight">30</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Next time, don't start your question with `I want to`. We're not your servants.

Comment: @roshan: So do it! What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
 $("td.remove_highlight span.highlights").removeClass("highlights");
```